# Distribution of product of two Complex random variable $Z = X*Y$, where, $X,Y \in C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to find the product distribution function of two independent complex random variables

$Z = X*Y$

Where, $X,Y \in C$.

Let, the distribution of $X$ is Raleigh fading is ${f_x}(x;\sigma ) = \frac{x}{{{\sigma ^2}}}{e^{ - {x^2}/(2{\sigma ^2})}}$.

The distribution of $Y$ is any discrete/continuous distribution.

1. How should I approach to find the distribution of $Z$?

****Note: I know that for real random variable e.g. $X,Y \in R$, the product distribution can be expressed as,

${f_z}(z) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{f_X}(x){f_Y}(z|x)\frac{1}{{|x|}}dx} $

Any suggestions would help.